# "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider" when hosting site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, host

I recently migrated my Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data to an MSSQL Database, and I am now getting the above error when loading my page externally.

This is my system.data tag in my web.config:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe" />
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

My host has an associated MSSQL Database that i connected to and transferred the data. What changes do I need to make to my web.config to make my site work with my new database?

This is the full error, without the stacktrace:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiG8G.png

Comment: try config from this http://cyberwarzone.com/fix-obtain-provider-factory-data-provider-named-mysql-data-mysqlclient/

improvise as required